# htaccess mod_rewrite Shorten to a SEO friendly URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this address

```
http://www.nfrases.com/tag.php?id_tag=10&id_frase=508
```

that I would like to make it a lot shorter and more SEO friendly to something like (I don't know ... open to suggestions) `http://www.nfrases.com/tag/10/508` or `http://www.tag10name.nfrases.com/508`

I need help with how to code this, because a simple thing as trying to make the address always `http://www.nfrases.com` case the user goes to `http://nfrases.com` or `www.nfrases.com` I tried and failed :(

Used this code by the way:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.nfrases.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.nfrases.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.nfrases.com/tag.php?id_tag=10&id_frase=508

becomes

http://www.nfrases.com/10/508

with this in your .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/(.*)/?$ /tag.php?id_tag=$1&id_frase=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Untested. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Serk! That worked out fine! But I had a change of hear :| I think it would be better for SEO if I have the tag name on the address instead of the Tag ID. How would you do a generic rule for these links: http://www.nfrases.com/tag.php?tag_nome=vida AND http://www.nfrases.com/tag.php?tag_nome=vida&id_frase=1234

Comment: Can you provide the desired output of those links? For the first one do you want nfrases.com/tag_nome/vida or nfrases.com/vida ?? How about for the second one? Can you provide me with an example output you are looking for?

Comment: Great! Glad you can help! I guess the best way would be to have www.nfrases.com/vida that would generate a random phrase for the tag 'vida' (means life btw :)) and www.nfrases.com/vida/xxx would point specifically for the phrase with the id_frase = xxx

Comment: So for you to do `/vida` and `/vida/xxx` your `RewriteRule` would look like this: `RewriteRule ^tag/([0-9]+)(/([0-9]+))?$ tag.php?id_tag=$1&id_frase=$3` Again, untested as I don't have access to apache right now.

Comment: Also ... I do seem to lose the input parameters and the $_GET['id_frase'] wont work right.

Comment: Hmm.. sorry, I'm kinda stuck here as I don't have access to apache right now. Maybe you could do ask this in another question.

Comment: Will do! thanks for the patiente and for your try! :) Cheers mate